# Solutions to $\prod_{i=1}^{k}p_i=\sum_{i=1}^{k}p_i^2$ with $p_i$ distincts primes

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

Does $\prod_{i=1}^{k}p_i=\sum_{i=1}^{k}p_i^2$ with $p_i$ distincts primes and $k\geq2$ have a solution ?

Here is what I already know :

- There is no solutions if $k\equiv0\bmod2$ or if $k\equiv0\bmod3$.
- It's a special case of Hurwitz equation ($A\prod_{i=1}^{k}p_i=\sum_{i=1}^{k}p_i^2$) with $A=1$ and a fondamental solution can't contain coprimes.
- There is no solution for $k\leq12$.

This question is related (sub case) to this [one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1309427/can-a-number-be-equal-to-the-sum-of-the-squares-of-its-prime-divisors/1378915#1378915)

Comment: [Related](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1117435/integer-solutions-to-prod-limits-i-1nx-i-sum-limits-i-1nx-i2/1128359#1128359)

Comment: Because the only fondamental solution for $k=5$ and $A=1$ is (1,1,3,3,4). As it contains coprimes, this solutions will never generate a solution without coprimes. (new solutions are obtained by subtiting elements $p_x$ by ${A*\prod_{i=1}^{k}p_i\over p_x}-p_x$)

Comment: If the fondamental solution contains coprimes then there is no solution (for that fondamental solution) because all the "child solutions" of this fondamental solution **will** contain coprimes (in the case of (1,1,3,3,4), substitying a $3$ leads to (1,1,3,9,4) etc.) and we want a solution with distincts primes.

Comment: I see now the reason: if we have a solution containing two element which are not coprime **then** the generated solutions will always contain two elements which are not coprime. for example if we have $(a_0,b_0,c_0,\cdots)$ a fundamental solution with $d=\gcd(a_0,b_0)>1$ then always in the next solutions we will have $\gcd(a_n,b_n)>d$ (yes in a certain order) and this implies that there is no solution for the case $k=5$. (until now, I don't understand your explication). It would be helpful for other people to see your reasoning so I think it's better to include that (why k<12) in the question