# Conjecture: Is the identity $2^5-5^2=2+5$ unique?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, conjectures

Yet again a conjecture!

Motivated by [Catalan's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_conjecture) and a [recent question of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286093/conjecture-no-positive-integer-can-be-written-as-xyyx-in-more-than-one-way), I conjecture that

> For distinct, positive integers $a,b$, the only solution to this equation $$a^b-b^a=a+b\tag1$$ is $(a,b)=(2,5).$

It is of anticipation that there will be much fewer solutions for increasing $a,b$ since the values that $a^b-b^a$ are extremely restricted due to the small growth rate of $a+b$.

Plotting [$x^y-y^x=x+y$](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/kmgr8bpodl) on Desmos strongly suggests that are no other solutions other than those on the line $y=x$.

Is there something obvious I'm missing to solve this?