# Are $3^6-6^3$ and $4^8-8^4$ the only sums of four $a^b-b^a,1\lt a\lt b$ numbers?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, reference-request, examples-counterexamples, recreational-mathematics

**Question**

How many numbers of form $a_0^{b_0}-b_0^{a_0}$ are a "nontrivial" sum of four such numbers $a_i^{b_i}-b_i^{a_i}$ ?

The "nontrivial" means: all unordered pairs $\{a_i,b_i\}$ are distinct, $a_i^{b_i}\ne b_i^{a_i}$ and $1 \lt a_i\lt b_i$.

This implies that such summands are positive (*are in OEIS [A045575](https://oeis.org/A045575)*), except $2^3-3^2 = -1$.

The only "nontrivial" examples I could find are:

$$\begin{align}
(2^5-5^2) + (2^6-6^2) + (2^7-7^2) + (4^5-5^4) &= (3^6-6^3)  \\
(2^8-8^2)+ (4^5-5^4) + (4^6-6^4) + (3^{10}-10^3)  &= (4^8-8^4)
\end{align}$$

> Are these two the only such numbers?

For comparison, I suspect such sums with less than four summands do not exist, and that there are infinitely many such sums with more than four summands. With four summands exactly, I have only these two examples, hence this question.

Are there any other references (*than ones listed in OEIS [A045575](https://oeis.org/A045575)*) on problems related to $x^y-y^x$ numbers?

**Background**

These two numbers correspond to the following two [Base-Exponent Invariant](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3795656/318073) numbers:

$$\begin{array}{}
1464 &=& 2^5 + 2^6 + 2^7 + 4^5 + 6^3 &=& 5^2 + 6^2 + 7^2 + 5^4 + 3^6 \\
68521 &=& 2^8 + 4^5 + 4^6 + 3^{10} + 8^4 &=& 8^2 + 5^4 + 6^4 + 10^3 + 4^8
\end{array}$$

That is, these numbers are a special case of the "Base-Exponent Invariant" numbers.

I call these "Order-$5$ Genus-$1$" Base-Exponent Invariant numbers $1464,68521\in G^{(5)}_1$.

In general, I have found only $14$ examples (*see "short examples" in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3816478/318073)*) of "Order-$5$ Base-Exponent Invariant numbers". The largest known example is around $6\cdot 10^6$, while the next one, if it exists, is larger than  $10^{16}$.

**General near examples**

I've searched for smallest "error" $e(n)$ such that "some elements plus the error" are a sum of the "other elements" from the "best" 5-subset of [A045575](https://oeis.org/A045575) among "nontrivial" 5-subsets whose largest element is the $n$*th* nonzero term of [A045575](https://oeis.org/A045575).

If $e(n)=0$ (and $n\ge 5$) then we have general examples(s) and $(n,0)$ is colored *blue* (or *green* if corresponding example is also "Genus-$1$"). If $e(n)=\pm 1$ we have a "near example" (colored *red*). Else, we have a black point $(n,\log e(n))$. For $n$ up to $100$, we have the log plot of errors:

[image]

Notice that for $n\gt 43$, we have no general examples, and for $n\gt 25$ we have no "Genus-$1$" examples (*the examples I'm asking about in this question*), so far.

It would seem that new examples are very large and rare or do not exist. However, notice the far right "near example" (*red* point) at $n=83$, which gives us hope

$$
(2^8-8^2) + (2^{16}-16^2) + (4^{16}-16^4) + (2^{32}-32^2)  =  (2^{33}-33^2) \color{red}{+1}
$$

that maybe a large example could exist.

> Do there exist any larger general examples, Genus-1 examples or near examples?

Comment: $2^3-3^2=-1$ is not the only exception. $2^4-4^2 = 0$. That should be also consider as trivial?

Comment: @jjagmath It is included as trivial: The "nontrivial" condition contains "$a_i^{b_i}\ne b_i^{a_i}$", implying summands that equal zero are not being considered.